# Android SugarORM ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, sugarorm

The last days I get this error, but only on devices with Android older than 4.4.

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at com.orm.util.ReflectionUtil.getDomainClass(ReflectionUtil.java:273)
            at com.orm.util.ReflectionUtil.getDomainClasses(ReflectionUtil.java:257)
            at com.orm.SchemaGenerator.createDatabase(SchemaGenerator.java:37)
            at com.orm.SugarDb.onCreate(SugarDb.java:26)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.orm.SugarDb.getDB(SugarDb.java:36)
            at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:194)
            at com.orm.SugarRecord.listAll(SugarRecord.java:99)
            at co.getcontrol.service.AccountsService.getAnyAccount(AccountsService.java:142)
            at co.getcontrol.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:191)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5244)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.Error
            at com.timgroup.jgravatar.internal.com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator$1.run(UnsignedBytes.java:259)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45)
            at com.timgroup.jgravatar.internal.com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator.<clinit>(UnsignedBytes.java:248)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at com.orm.util.ReflectionUtil.getDomainClass(ReflectionUtil.java:273)
            at com.orm.util.ReflectionUtil.getDomainClasses(ReflectionUtil.java:257)
            at com.orm.SchemaGenerator.createDatabase(SchemaGenerator.java:37)
            at com.orm.SugarDb.onCreate(SugarDb.java:26)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.orm.SugarDb.getDB(SugarDb.java:36)
            at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:194)
            at com.orm.SugarRecord.listAll(SugarRecord.java:99)
            at co.getcontrol.service.AccountsService.getAnyAccount(AccountsService.java:142)
            at co.getcontrol.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:191)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5244)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and as you can see, there is SugarDb. This is not completely my project and I don't know how the Sugar added to the project - there is no such dependency in gradle and no extern library in the folder. Moreover you can see, that there is jgravatar library in the error log. But the app craches in the place, where isn't any jgravatar object. It is used later in other activities.

I guess it's something wrong with libraries, because the code works on other devices.

Comment: Could someone may be comment on how to interpret this log - having 2 errors - java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and  "Caused by: java.lang.Error" ?

Comment: I have been getting these as well. Really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was jgravatar library. I changed it to [gravatar-android](https://github.com/tkeunebr/gravatar-android) and now it woks again